# Missing gems after successful deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I deploy my rails app via capistrano 3.14.

Deploy is successful but when I try to start app message "Could find  in any of the sources. Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems." is shown.

The problem is that gems are installed but on location /home/user/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0 so I don't know what to do now and how to solve this problem.

In `deploy.rb` file I set up configuration for RVM integration with capistrano and that looks like:

```
set :default_environment, {
  'PATH' => "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8@<mygemset>/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/bin:$PATH",
  'RUBY_VERSION' => 'ruby-2.3.8',
  'GEM_HOME'     => '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8@<mygemset>',
  'GEM_PATH'     => '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8@<mygemset>:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8@global',
  'BUNDLE_PATH'  => '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8@<mygemset>'
}
```

Also I created rvmrc trust task in `deploy.rb` file

```
namespace :rvmrc do
  desc "Trust rvmrc file" 
  task :trust do
    on roles(:all) do
      execute :rvm, "rvmrc trust #{release_path}"
    end
  end
end
before 'deploy:set_current_revision', 'rvmrc:trust'
```

If anyone has an idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with installation rvm for multi users. When I installed rvm correctly everything works as expected.